# Unable to delete an unzipped folder using golang

Tags: go, copy, directory, unzip

I wrote code that unzips a file in a particular location then copies the contents of the folder to outside where the folder is unzipped then it removes the folder.

This is the Code I wrote:

```
package main

 import (
   "os"
   "flag"
   "fmt"
   "io"
   "path/filepath"
   "os/exec"
   "archive/zip"
   "time"
 )

func RemoveContents(dir string) error {
    d, err := os.Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    names, err := d.Readdirnames(-1)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, name := range names { 
            err = os.RemoveAll(filepath.Join(dir, name))
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
    }
    d.Close()
    return nil
}


func CopyFile(source string, dest string) (err error) {
     sourcefile, err := os.Open(source)
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }

     defer sourcefile.Close()

     destfile, err := os.Create(dest)
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }

     defer destfile.Close()

     _, err = io.Copy(destfile, sourcefile)
     if err == nil {
         sourceinfo, err := os.Stat(source)
         if err != nil {
             err = os.Chmod(dest, sourceinfo.Mode())
         }

     }

     return
 }

 func CopyDir(source string, dest string) (err error) {

     // get properties of source dir
     sourceinfo, err := os.Stat(source)
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }

     // create dest dir

     err = os.MkdirAll(dest, sourceinfo.Mode())
     if err != nil {
         return err
     }

     directory, _ := os.Open(source)

     objects, err := directory.Readdir(-1)

     for _, obj := range objects {

         sourcefilepointer := source + "/" + obj.Name()

         destinationfilepointer := dest + "/" + obj.Name()


         if obj.IsDir() {
             // create sub-directories - recursively
             err = CopyDir(sourcefilepointer, destinationfilepointer)
             if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
             }
         } else {
             // perform copy
             err = CopyFile(sourcefilepointer, destinationfilepointer)
             if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
             }
         }

     }
     return
 }




 func main() {
    flag.Parse() // get the source and destination directory

    source_dir := flag.Arg(0) // get the source directory from 1st argument

    dest_dir := flag.Arg(1) // get the destination directory from the 2nd argument

        os.MkdirAll("E:\\go\\copyDirectory\\myFile.zip",0777)
    zipFilePath := "E:\\go\\copyDirectory\\myFile.zip"
    tempWrkDir := "E:\\go\\copyDirectory\\"

    //Read zip file and get path handle.
    fileHandleReader, err := zip.OpenReader(zipFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    //open zip file and read all the folder and files inside
    for _, fileReadHandler := range fileHandleReader.Reader.File {
        //read the file or folder handle inside zip
        fileOpenHandle, err := fileReadHandler.Open()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        defer fileOpenHandle.Close()
    targetUnZipPath := filepath.Join(tempWrkDir, fileReadHandler.Name)
    if fileReadHandler.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(targetUnZipPath, fileReadHandler.Mode())
            //fmt.Println("Creating directory", path)
        }else {
            // create new dummy file to copy original file.
            newTempFileHandle, err := os.OpenFile(targetUnZipPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, fileReadHandler.Mode())

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            defer newTempFileHandle.Close()
            //copying original file to dummy file.
            if _, err = io.Copy(newTempFileHandle, fileOpenHandle); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        }
    }
      time.Sleep(1000*time.Millisecond)

      fmt.Println("Source :" + source_dir)

      // check if the source dir exist
      src, err := os.Stat(source_dir)
     if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

     if !src.IsDir() {
       fmt.Println("Source is not a directory")
       os.Exit(1)
    }

   // create the destination directory
   fmt.Println("Destination :"+ dest_dir)

   /*_, err = os.Open(dest_dir)
   if !os.IsNotExist(err) {
     fmt.Println("Destination directory already exists. Abort!")
     os.Exit(1)
   }*/

   err = CopyDir(source_dir, dest_dir)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   } else {
      fmt.Println("Directory copied")
   }
    err = RemoveContents("./myFiles")
       if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERRR:::",err)
       }
    //time.Sleep(10000*time.Millisecond)
 }
```

The problem is that everything works fine except for deleting the folder. The folder has only one file in it. The location of the file is as follows:

```
E:\go\copyDirectory\myfile\mytextfile.txt
```

The Location of the zip file is as follows:

```
 E:\go\copyDirectory\myfile.zip
```

The zip file has only one text file. The File inside the zip file is as follows:

```
E:\go\copyDirectory\myfile.zip\myfile\mytextfile.txt
```

The error I get is:

```
ERRR::: remove myfile\mytextfile.txt: The process cannot
access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't closing the file. This:

```
defer newTempFileHandle.Close()
```

Is run when main finishes, which is after:

```
err = RemoveContents("./myFiles")
```

You can wrap that bit of code in an unnamed function:

```
    func() {
        //read the file or folder handle inside zip
        fileOpenHandle, err := fileReadHandler.Open()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        defer fileOpenHandle.Close()
        targetUnZipPath := filepath.Join(tempWrkDir, fileReadHandler.Name)
        if fileReadHandler.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(targetUnZipPath, fileReadHandler.Mode())
            //fmt.Println("Creating directory", path)
        } else {
            // create new dummy file to copy original file.
            newTempFileHandle, err := os.OpenFile(targetUnZipPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, fileReadHandler.Mode())

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            defer newTempFileHandle.Close()
            //copying original file to dummy file.
            if _, err = io.Copy(newTempFileHandle, fileOpenHandle); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        }
    }()
```

And then your defer will happen before you try and remove the files. I would recommend pulling this out into a named function though.